# Return Null in View Data in ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, view, return, viewdata

I have a controller  and receive correct data from my service and repository( I check it with breakpoint)

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        CountViewModel adminContentCount = await _siteService.AdminContentCount();
        ViewData["UnreadTicketMessage"] = await _siteService.ShowUnReadTicketMessages();

        return View(adminContentCount);
    }
```

But when sent to view , it returns null

view:

```
    @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index;
 
    IEnumerable<AdminDashboardUnreadMessage> unreadTicketMessagemessages = ViewData["UnreadTicketMessage"] as IEnumerable<AdminDashboardUnreadMessage>;

}
```

why?

Comment: There might be a casting problem. Can you check ShowUnReadTicketMessages returns IEnumerable<AdminDashboardUnreadMessage>?

Comment: You need to check the type of `await _siteService.ShowUnReadTicketMessages();`.If the type of `IEnumerable<AdminDashboardUnreadMessage> unreadTicketMessagemessages = ViewData["UnreadTicketMessage"] as IEnumerable<AdminDashboardUnreadMessage>;` is `IEnumerable<AdminDashboardUnreadMessage>`,it will work.As  `İbrahim ULUDAĞ` said,it may be a casting problem.